# How to compare elements and remove those not complying with condition

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to compare elements of one row with the elements of the next row of a numpy array. More precisely

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[10,12,13],[20,23,24],[45,46,49],[51,52,53]])
```

I know I can have the differences using

```
np.diff(a,axis=0)
```

which returns:

```
array([[ 9, 10, 10],
   [10, 11, 11],
   [25, 23, 25],
   [ 6,  6,  4]])
```

But how can I get the initial 'a' array without elements that have a difference <=10 with the next row. Particularly, the difference in the third column.
The array I'd like to get is;

```
array([[1,2,3],[20,23,24],[45,46,49]])
```

I'm pretty sure there is an (easy) way to do it with numpy. Maybe with `np.where`?

Comment: The first row does not comply with your stated condition.  Its difference with the next row is `<= 10` (namely, it equals 10).  Could you clarify if the condition or the expected output are wrong?

Answer (score 3):

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [10, 12, 13],
       [20, 23, 24],
       [45, 46, 49],
       [51, 52, 53]])

In [9]: d = np.diff(a,axis=0)

In [10]: d
Out[10]: 
array([[ 9, 10, 10],
       [10, 11, 11],
       [25, 23, 25],
       [ 6,  6,  4]])
```

Form the boolean array which is True when the difference is greater than 10:

```
In [20]: d > 10
Out[20]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Find the rows where at least one element is True:

```
In [21]: (d > 10).any(axis=1)
Out[21]: array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Prepend a `True` to select the first row of `a`:

```
In [22]: np.r_[True, (d > 10).any(axis=1)]
Out[22]: array([ True, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Select rows of `a`:

```
In [23]: a[np.r_[True, (d > 10).any(axis=1)]]
Out[23]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [20, 23, 24],
       [45, 46, 49]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for the late answer. If I want the condition to apply on the third column only, I'll use (d[:, 2] > 10) instead of (d > 10).any(axis=1). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account you want differences in the third column to be <= 10:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[10,12,13],[20,23,24],[45,46,49],[51,52,53]])

In [4]: d = np.diff(a, axis=0)

In [12]: idxs = (d[:, 2] > 10)

In [15]: a[idxs, :]
Out[15]:
array([[10, 12, 13],
       [20, 23, 24]])
```

Notice you just need an array of booleans (`idxs` for "indexes") to slice the original array.

The first row of `a` does not comply with the condition as it is stated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for the late answer. I should have said "difference with the **previous** row". _Mea culpa_. I think the condition returned by idxs (False, True, True, False) applies to the first row (False); consequently, no condition is set on the fifth row. Thus, I think we should prepend idxs with True (or False). Thks

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different method compared to the others, maybe this aligns better with your thought process?

```
In [44]: d = np.diff(a[:,2])

In [45]: idx, = np.where(d <= 10)

In [46]: np.delete(a, idx, axis=0)
Out[46]: 
array([[10, 12, 13],
       [20, 23, 24],
       [51, 52, 53]])

In [47]: np.delete(a, idx+1, axis=0)
Out[47]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [20, 23, 24],
       [45, 46, 49]])
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate. All this helps me understand how to use numpy... which is really fast!